# Sharepoint 2013 / Accordion on Content Web Query

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

this is my first time posting although I've been using stackoverflow as an information source for long time.
In Sharepoint 2013 I have a page with a Content Web Query Part that collects all Open Tasks from all the sub-sites' Task Lists. All these tasks are grouped by their sub-site name. By adding a custom content editor I'm trying to add "accordion" functionality to the Content Web Query Part. All the Task1, Task2, etc. as per the below code are nicely collapsed or hidden, but when I click on a groupheader then all the tasks including the groupheaders disappear. The behavior I'm looking for is when someone clicks on a groupheader the underlying tasks appear and all other "visible" tasks if any are hidden again. I've been trying many different code, but nothing seems to work. The below was coming from post [jquery in sharepoint 2010 webquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060237/accordion-on-sharepoint-2010-content-query)

The script on the webpage looks like this:

```html
<div WebPartID="....." WebPartID2="..." id="WebPartWPQ2" class="ms-WPBody noindex ">
<div id="...." class="cbq-layout-main"><ul class="dfwp-column dfwp-list" 
<li class="dfwp-item">
<div class="groupheader item band"> Sub-site 1 name</div>
<ul class="dfwp-list">
<li class="dfwp-item">
<div class="item">
<div class="link-item"><a href="URL1">Task1</a>
<div class="description"></div></div></div></li>
<li class="dfwp-item"><div class="groupheader item band">Sub-site 2 name</div>
<ul class="dfwp-list">
<li class="dfwp-item">
<div class="item">
<div class="link-item"><a href="URL2">Task1</a>
<div class="description"></div></div></div></li>
<li class="dfwp-item">
<div class="item">
<div class="link-item"><a href="URL3">Task2</a>
<div class="description"></div></div></div></li>
<li class="dfwp-item">
<div class="item">
<div class="link-item"><a href="URL4">Task3</a>
<div class="description"></div></div></div></li>
```

I added the following code to the page using a Content Editor Web Part to create an accordion style:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>



$(document).ready(function(){

 // Detect if user view or edit the page
 if($("#MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName").val() == "Browse"){
  // Register accordion
  accordion();
 }
 
})

var accordion = function(){
 
 /* Do fancy easing */
 $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";

 /* Slide up all link items and hide them */
 $(".dfwp-list .item").not(".groupheader").slideUp("fast");
 
 /* Binding a click event handler to the links: */
 $(".groupheader").click(function(e){

  
  /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
  //MAKE THE ACCORDION CLOSE ON THE SECOND CLICK
         var $content = $(this).children(".dfwp-list .item");

         var visible = $content.is(':visible');

         $(".dfwp-list .item:visible").toggle('normal');

         if (!visible)
             $content.toggle('normal');
  
 })
}</script>]]>
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle so that we could try to help you.

Comment: Adi, I'm not great at this and I did use something like it to create the code above. The top script is only a simplified portion of the entire webpage. Unfortunately this is behind a firewall of my employer, so it can't be shared. Can you explain with a bit more detail please what you want me to do?

Comment: The core problem is that I do not know how to select the linked items that belong to a groupheader that when clicked upon should unhide only these linked items. The problem rest with the code underneath the $(".groupheader").click(function(e){ line.

Comment: Of course, I understand you're having a problem. But If you need help you gotta provide an environment for people to "play" with your code. For this reason, you have jsFiddle. You don't have to "expose" your real page to the world. All you need to do is create HTML content by hand, similar to what you get in your "real" solution and add your dependencies like scripts or plugins that you use. On top of that add your jQuery code. That way, we can actually experiment with it until we come up with a solution. Elements like WebPartWPQ are not needed. You don't need sharepoint to solve jQuery issue.